# Java Library / API for share counts (count likes, tweets, +1s)

Tags: java, facebook, twitter

I've seen individual solutions to querying the tweet count, share count etc:
Some are client side, some are server side, but they are all very simple and use public JSON / REST APIs

e.g.

[How to get share counts using graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699270/how-to-get-share-counts-using-graph-api)

[jquery plugin or routine to find tweet count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016082/jquery-plugin-or-routine-to-find-tweet-count)

There is this [GitHub project](https://github.com/vitobotta/share_counts), but it's in Ruby (I need Java unfortunately, though I can use JRuby as a last resort) and also haven't been updated in 2 years (which is ages in terms of public APIs, e.g. Twitter)

Is there a any Java library that gets you the share / votes / likes / tweets count for any given URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the language of your choice to make a HTTP GET request like so:

https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url,normalized_url,share_count,like_count,comment_count,total_count,commentsbox_count,comments_fbid,click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url='http://www.facebook.com/nokia'

Or any url:

https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url,normalized_url,share_count,like_count,comment_count,total_count,commentsbox_count,comments_fbid,click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url='http://nokia.com'

Then parse the JSON.

Paste that link to a browser and you'll see the JSON data